# Why do I need to wait for 2 days to delete my post?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I have [posted](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/249/what-to-do-when-nothing-to-do) a bad question *(I know that I should have read the FAQ first, I apologize)*, my first question in this SE site, and I want to delete it because it just lower my reputation but I at least need to wait for 2 days to delete it.

Why was it like this? In other SE sites, I can immediately delete my bad question(s) so that it wont acquire such large number of down-votes.

I am really enthusiastic in supporting this site and I do not want new users to see such bad question. Again, I apologize for posting such non-constructive question and I'll try my best not to post such kind of question again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several questions on Meta StackOverflow about this. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119297/166214), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56149/166214) or [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1588/166214) for example. [This is a discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117933/allow-the-author-to-delete-their-own-question-after-closure-if-other-rules-perm) about changing the behavior.

It's not specific to this site. The reason is to allow a post to be reopened if it was closed in error, which happens.

A work around is to flag it for deletion and a mod can delete it for you.

Comment: Thanks. I follow the workaround.

Answer (score 5):

I am actually a fan of not deleting questions right away because they serve as examples of what not to ask here. When it comes time to edit the [FAQ](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/faq), it's just as important to list what is not on topic, if not more, as it is to list what is on topic.

When we only focus on what is allowed, we leave virtually an infinite amount of possibilities for the disallowed that we don't think of.

Additionally, having examples of bad questions also helps put things into better perspective as a moderator. They act as a sanity check for us when we examine a question that we're not sure about. I know when I see questions like this, it makes me realize that maybe some other questions that weren't perfect actually weren't quite so bad.

By the way, this is meant as no offense to you. We've all had questions closed or missed reading the FAQ at one point in time. I appreciate you following up on this, and admitting your mistake, and helping to determine when or how something should be deleted.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, but the reason OP wanted to delete his question is because people continued to downvote it, even well after it was closed. Leaving a question around as an example is fine but it seems unfair to require the asker to continue to slowly lose rep because of it.